# Java MVC, Share Models between controllers?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, models

I am implementing the MVC structure that this website talks about http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html

I am struggling to work out of to open new windows that have a new controller? Do i do this in the default controller? 
Also how would i share common models between multiple controllers?

For example, 
i have a LoginController, LoginView and a Employee Model. They login and i want to open up the main application. The employee model will need to be used in the main controller and probably other controllers how would that be implemented?

Thanks

Comment: To skip redundant communicationS between controllers ,i mean A->B and B->A , A->C ,C-->B ...etc,I suggest to create Register Class which contains shared instance of Model and has an access from controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is quite interesting. it often comes up for me as well. Wether you use MVC or, a pattern I prefer now : MVP (with passive views), it looks like those pattern just define a normative way of coding stuff at the form level. I mean that both are interested in jframes, or activities for android (let's call them forms as [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) does).

Nevertheless, there is a gap to model larger applications with multiple forms sharing models and controllers. I would be interested in digging out this question in a collaborative efforts. If you are interested, let me know, we will find a way to communicate directly.

An idea I got would be to have some kind of super model that would act as a factory to provide other submodels and that would be used by another component, responsible of the wiring of submodels, subviews and sub forms. That's just a preliminary idea and I wish other people would share their practices and experiences on that question.